# Two <p> tag set in one line?

Tags: html, css

```html
    <p style="display:inline"> First Name<p id="name"> Ram. </p> <p>
```

Output:  First Name Ram.
How to get this answer?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use the paragraph element for this span of text? Surely span makes more sense and would give you the behaviour you want.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid which can cause unexpected results when applying CSS or JS on it. A `<p>` is not allowed to contain another `<p>`, so when the browser parses this you'll actually end up with a structure like: `<p style="display:inline"> First Name</p><p id="name"> Ram. </p> <p></p>`

Comment: try:  display: inline-block;

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `.inline` class to both paragraphs. Consider using `span` instead.

```css
.inline {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<p class="inline">First Name</p>
<p class="inline" id="name">Ram.</p>
<p>
```

Comment: Consider using a better class name. A class should should describe _what_ something _is_, not _how_ something _looks_. Here, _First Name_ seems to be a label for the name "Ram", so `<span class="label">` is more semantically informative.

Comment: @StephenP In this case, it is a general helper class, but I get your point.

Answer (score 5):

The `< p >` tag defines a paragraph. you need add a `< span >` tag

```html
<p><span>First Name</span><span id="name"> Ram.</span></p>
```

you can see work here http://codepen.io/felo89/pen/MKweJd?editors=100

Comment: You don't need the `style="display:inline"` — a `<span>` is already an inline element.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `display:inline-block;` to enable block-level elements to sit adjacent to one another:

```css
p {
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>First Name</p>
<p id="name">Ram.</p>
```